# Glassfish JDBC Realm not working with Umlauts

Tags: jdbc, encoding, glassfish

My glassfish 3.1.2 server has a jdbc realm for authentication. I'm using sha-256 as digest algorithm and base64 as encoding for the password. I try to login with a simple swing client.

It works fine with normal characters, but it doesn't if the password contains german umlauts (e.g. ä,ö,ü,...).

As java uses UTF-16 for internal string encoding, I set the charset of the digest algorithm in the jdbc realm also to UTF-16 but it still doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20491?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) in Glassfish 3...